# Ansible No File in Directory docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

Hello I'm trying to start the docker compose (docker-compose_mysql.yml up) but ansible says no files in the directory. I've already looked at other solutions on github and stackoverflow but nothing that has allowed me to solve my problem.
Thanks you :)

### my playbook

```
---

- name: Mettre en place Redmine - mySQL
  connection: localhost
  hosts: localhost
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:

    - name: install docker-py
      pip: name=docker-py

    - name: Installer le docker compose
      command: sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
      register: command1
    - debug: var=command1.stdout_lines


    - name: Installer le docker compose
      command: pip install docker-compose
    
    - name: download docker compose
      command: wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine/master/docker-compose-mysql.yml
      register: command2
    - debug: var=command2.stdout_lines


    - name: docker compose run
      command: docker-compose-mysql.yml up-d
      register: command3
    - debug: var=command3.stdout_lines
```

my error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "docker-compose-mysql.yml up-d", "msg": "[Errno 2] Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type: b'docker-compose-mysql.yml'", "rc": 2}
```

[file docker-compose-mysql in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diZl5.png)

Comment: The simple and obvious explanation would be that the file does not exist. Please [edit] to indicate proof that the file is there, and ideally provide a [mre].

Comment: hi tripleee i have update my question. you can see the file is present in directory and i have update the playbook minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Like the answer you got suggests, the file is not _there_ where Docker is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - name: copy sql schema
  hosts: test-mysql
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    - name: Docker compose
      command: docker-compose -f {{ name }}_compose.yml up -d
```

Then, either move {{ name }}_compose.yml to the directory or provide an absolute path in command: docker-compose -f [abs_path]{{ name }}_compose.yml up -d

Comment: hi fakhrulasa thanks it resolve but  i have  new error  now is "error format for exec 8" .